# SMTP Authentication error while while sending mail from outlook using python language

Tags: python, email

```
import smtplib


smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)

smtpObj.ehlo()

smtpObj.starttls()

smtpObj.login('xxx@gmail.com', ' abcde')

smtpObj.sendmail('xxx@gmail.com', 'yyyy@outlook.com', 'Subject: So long.\nDear Alice, so long and thanks for all the fish. Sincerely, Bob')

{}

smtpObj.close()
```

The error I am getting

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BM1PR01CA0150.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]').
```

Comment: Have you been through the suggestions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045404/jenkins-email-extension-plugin-unsuccessful-authentication-with-office-365-accou/49287610#49287610. Especially double-checking your password and email address.

Comment: How to check if the email address was created as a shared mailbox?

Answer (score 9):

Most likely, the authenticated SMTP (SMTP AUTH protocol) is disabled in your Exchange Online organization.

SMTP AUTH can be enabled/disabled on the organization level, or per-mailbox. Because SMTP AUTH only uses basic authentication, Microsoft recommends to disable it on the organization level and enable it only for individual accounts that still require it.

If [security defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults) are enabled in the organization, then SMTP AUTH is disabled.

SMTP AUTH can be enabled in Microsoft 365 admin center or using Exchange Online Powershell.

To make it simple, to enable SMTP AUTH for a single account:

1. Go to the Microsoft 365 admin center (https://admin.microsoft.com/) > **Users** > **Active users**.
2. Select the user you are going to send emails from, and go to the **Mail** tab.
3. In the **Email apps** section click **Manage email apps**.
4. Enable **Authenticated SMTP** and click **Save changes**.

After that you should be able to authenticate using the respective account.

**Important**: You need admin rights in your Office 365 organization to do that. Otherwise, ask your O365 org admin for help.

Further details: https://learn.microsoft.com/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission

Answer (score 0):

@wombatonfire gave a terrific answer, but if for any reason those steps aren't possible (as was my situation), the following solved the OP problem for me.

I'm on a Mac. Can't get to admin center. Had to use powershell.
Also, powershell on my Mac had to connect to MSFT exchange server before I could change the setting for my mailbox. The following makes email work as designed.

There is a critical hoop to jump through to make this all work.
To connect your Mac to MSFT Exchange server, your Mac must use TLS1.2 from/via/through OpenSSL1.0. OpenSSL1.1 is a no go.

Get a terminal window on your Mac:

```
Click LaunchPad, type "term", click Terminal
```

In the terminal window, check what version(s) of OpenSSL are on your Mac:

```
>ls -al /usr/local/Cellar/openssl*
```

See which what version is active:

```
>openssl version -a
```

OpenSSL 1.1.* is bad.
OpenSSL 1.0.* is good.

NORMALLY, you can use brew to switch versions of a package is active with:

```
>brew switch openssl 1.0.2s
>brew link --overwrite openssl
```

But I got this error: Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl.
So I had to get tricky.

Change PATH environment variable (just in this terminal session, not permanently).

```
>PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/bin:$PATH
```

Now the check, shows good version:

```
>openssl version -a
```

Next, I followed steps to install powershell documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7

Now, open powershell as admin.

```
>sudo su - root
<your mac password>
root>pwsh
```

At the powershell prompt, double check your powershell version. Version 7 is needed.

```
>$host.version
```

I have: 7.0.3 Revision -1

Check what modules are installed in powershell:

```
>Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

If "PowerShellGet" is not listed, install it:

```
>Install-Module -Name PowerShellGet -Force
```

This next step is critical to success on the Mac. Only the latest "preview version 2.0.4" of "ExchangeOnlineManagement" package is going to work on Mac.

I don't know if this is needed, but I uninstalled the released version of "ExchangeOnlineManagement" package with:

```
>Uninstall-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -RequiredVersion 2.0.3
```

If preview version not present, install it:

```
>Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -AllowPrerelease -Force
```

One last detail to take care of. Tell powershell what version of TLS you want "ExchangeOnlineManagement" package to use:

```
>[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Finally, it's time to connect to the mothership:
(Again, this is trickier on a Mac than in Windows, probably).

```
>Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName youremail@yourdomain
```

The above command will try to open a browser to a special authentication page. At least on my Mac, it couldn't. So:

```
COPY the giant link that gets displayed in the powershell window

PASTE the giant link into a web browser (I used Safari).
```

After you enter your Exchange credentials on that browser page, your powershell will show a progress bar for a short time, then magically be connected to MSFT Exchange server!

And the last step to set the SMTP setting on the mailbox you want to use:

```
Set-CASMailbox -Identity youremail@yourdomain -SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled $false
```

Lastly, apparently it's important to always explicitly disconnect (before closing the terminal window):

```
>Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
```

That's the ballgame. You are changing the "disabled" setting to false for each/any/all mailboxes you want to send email from.

Now the fully documented, oft repeated python code seen in the OP will use SMTP and TLS to send email via MSFT Exchange (until something else breaks it all again :-O ).

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi I have also encountered the same issue, Admins can’t allow the basic authentication for SMTP_AUTH.. but i have to do it using python script which is an automated script. Can you provide some inputs on this?

Comment: Sorry, @VipendraSingh. No ideas how that could be done any way other than I described.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @wombatonfire - very helpful - I have a small addition to your answer.

I tried for a few hours to setup up multiple email addresses to send mail from a Python script; all of the accounts I was working with showed Authenticated SMTP to be enabled on the Active User page, but I was still getting authentication errors.

Not until I *deselected* and *re-selected* the "Authenticated SMTP" checkbox for each account did the script work.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This should be a Comment to the referenced post. It does not qualify as an Answer as per SO guidelines (which are necessary for this platform to function well--it works differently than forums). Once you have enough reputation, you can comment anywhere. We appreciate your helpfulness and engagement. Welcome to SO. You can read more in the help section.